# Append text to multiple elements by class in Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm aware that what I want to do is modify the dom directly (a no no in vue.js), however the only alternatives I can think of will create much sloppier, and harder to maintain code.

### The Issue

I'm using vue-i18n and depending on what language the user has currently selected, I want to move the currency symbol to either in front or behind the price element (I have many elements which display price on many pages, over 150 in fact.)

### Alternatives

The best alternative I can think of is to add a `:class` binding to every single element that needs to be swapped, but to do that I'd have to add a ton of `v-ifs` + `mapGetters` + extra markup in each of the 15 separate pages the site has prices on (+ vuex logic). I'd also probably have to use `::before` and `::after` in css, make a class for each language and add the symbol within the `content: ''` of each.

### Newly Considered Solution

I thought it might be cleaner to simply use a `mounted` hook within `app.vue` which will run at `nextTick()` (so that the child view is fully rendered) then call a function to append the currency symbol either before or after all elements that include the `priceItem` class.

This way, I wouldn't have all the extra markup and `v-if`s polluting my template, although I'd be modifying the dom directly, albeit only once everything is rendered.

Are there any alternatives to the above which will allow me the simplicity I want, but still accomplish it using a Vue-type pattern?

### Example Code (app.vue)

```
    this.$nextTick(function () {
  // Get currently selected lang from i18n
  let lang = this.$i18n.locale

  // get correct currency symbol for selected language
  let symbol = ''

  switch (lang) {
    case 'ko':
      symbol = '₩'
      break
    case 'en':
      symbol = '$'
      break
    case 'ja':
      symbol = '¥'
      break
    case 'zh':
      symbol = '¥'
      break
    case 'es':
      symbol = '€'
      break
    case 'ru':
      symbol = '₽'
      break
  }

  // if lang is Korean append symbol after, else append before
  if (lang !== 'ko') {
    document
      .querySelector('priceItem')
      .insertAdjacentText('beforeBegin', symbol)
  } else {
    document
      .querySelector('priceItem')
      .insertAdjacentText('afterBegin', symbol)
  }
})
```

### EDIT:

Come to think of it, this would probably be better in a `computed` prop so that I can reassign the symbol whenever the user changes the language.

Comment: You can make the a computed property that listen on locale change event and return the symbol. I'll recommend you to use centralized store like vuex and use mapGetters.

Comment: What about using [`Intl.NumberFormat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/NumberFormat/NumberFormat) to format your numbers to display the correct currency symbol? Then you don't need to manually add currency symbols for all your prices.

Comment: @BallonUra could you give me a bit more detail as to why you would choose that? I know how to setup Vuex for that case, but it seems like quite a bit more code to achieve the same result. Not to mention repetitive functions in many pages

Comment: @Terry Actually, that's a great idea. I found a vue package that gives me some simple props using that extend that function. I think this is the simplest way to achieve my goal, and I couldn't get my code above to work correctly anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone looking for a quick solution for Vue, I used this package to solve my issue:

https://github.com/vinayakkulkarni/vue-intl-numberformat

I used the below format in my template:

```
<vue-intl-numberformat
   locale="en-IN"
   format-style="currency"
   :currency="getCurrency"
   :number="item.price"
 />
```

...

```
computed: {
   ...mapGetters(['getCurrency'])
}
```

Then I'm passing it the correct currency based on the actively selected lang in i18n via a getter.

(In my vuex store)

```
  getCurrency: (state) => {
    let activeLang = i18n.locale
    let currency = ''

    switch (activeLang) {
      case 'en':
        currency = 'USD'
        break
      case 'ko':
        currency = 'KRW'
        break
      case 'ja':
        currency = 'JPY'
        break
      case 'es' || 'fr' || 'it':
        currency = 'EUR'
        break
      case 'zh':
        currency = 'CNY'
        break
      case 'ru':
        currency = 'RUR'
        break
    }
    state.currency = currency
    return state.currency
  }
```

This seems like the cleanest solution thus far.